# Matching types with cond

Tags: clojure

Trying to find a more appropriate macro than `cond` to perform matching for predicate functions.

At the moment, I'm doing something like this:

```
(cond
  (map? x)        (do-map-code x)
  (sequential? x) (do-seq-code x)
  (keyword? x)    (do-kw-code x)
  :else              (do-generic-code x))
```

In an ideal world, I'd like to apply data as the first argument for each of the left hand conditions, allowing me to write this instead.

```
(cond x
  map?        (do-map-code x)
  sequential? (do-seq-code x)
  keyword?    (do-kw-code x)
  :else       (do-generic-code x))
```

Sort of like a backwards `condp`.

For reference, I know I could use `condp` with `type` and check against the type values. I just want to know whether this macro exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `condp` to do this:

```
(condp #(%1 %2) x
  map?        (do-map-code x)
  sequential? (do-seq-code x)
  keyword?    (do-kw-code x)
  (do-generic-code x))
```